# can't install repository in Forge

Tags: git, ssh

I do not know if it is acceptable to ask this here, but here it goes.

I am trying to deploy a git repository (from bitbucket) to a server (Digital Ocean 2.0) using forge of laravel.

The problem I am having is whenever I try to install the git repository on the domain I have. This is the error i am getting:

***Please make sure the following SSH key has been added as a "deploy
key" to your source control provider account:***

But whenever I try to use the SSH key in BitBucket, I keep getting this notification

***Someone has already registered that SSH key.***

What am I missing out or doing wrong?

I also see this error in forge notification area:

> Having SSH Problems?
>
> Please make sure that the following SSH key is placed in both the
> /home/forge/.ssh/authorized_keys file and the
> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys file on your server.

Comment: I have the same problem. Would like to know what the answer is...